# Send IP layer data

Tags: python, ip, raw-sockets

I'm trying to send IP packet data out a specific port and have the underlying linux network code do most of the heavy lifting in terms of ARP table lookup and creation of Layer 2 data (the Ethernet layer).

I have tried the following but the setsockopt keeps throwing the error 'Protocol not available'.

```
try:
    s = socket.socket( socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_IP )
    s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
    s.bind( (iface, ETH_P_IP) )

except socket.error, msg:
    raise Exception('Socket could not be created. Error: ' + str(msg[0]) + ', Message: ' + msg[1])

while True:

    px = '45000054604640004001e8abc0a83801c0a8386500006a8c0eac0001f3c661550000000066d70c0000000000101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f202122232425262728292a2b2c2d2e2f3031323334353637'.decode('hex')
    s.sendto(px, ('eth0', 0))
```

I've tried manually setting the IPPROTO_IP const to 0, 255 and none are supported... What am I missing?

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried using scapy?

Comment: Yup, doesn't do what I want it to do though. It maintains its own arp table but I want to use the hosts table.